# How to forward event downstream from a Punctuator instance in a ValueTransformer?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In KafkaStream, when implementing a **ValueTransformer** or **ValueTransformerWithKey**, on **transform()** call, I schedule a new Punctuator. When method **punctuate()** of the **Punctuator** is executed I want it to forward an event downstream using the context instance. However, the context instance seems not defined when part of a DSL topology.

Any clue on how to do this with a Transformer ?

Using the same logic in a Processor, implementing the low-level processor topology it works.

In ValueTransformerWithKey:

```
@Override 
    public Event transform(final String key, final Event event) { 
        this.context.schedule(timeout.toMillis(), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, new MyPunctuator(context, key, event));
        return null;
}
```

In MyPunctuator:

```
private class MytPunctuator implements Punctuator {
    private String key;
    private ProcessorContext context;
    private Event event;

    MyPunctuator(ProcessorContext context, String key, Event event)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.key = key;
        this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public void punctuate(final long timestamp) {
        context.forward(key, AlertEvent.builder().withSource(event).build());
        context.commit();
    }
}
```

When executing

```
myStream
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Event.serde()))
    .reduce((k, v) -> v)
    .transformValues(() -> valueTransformerWithKey)
    .toStream().to(ALARM_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), AlarmEvent.serde()));
```

I expect the Alarm event produced by the punctuator to be forwared to the ALARM topic once expired.

Instead I got the following exception: ProcessorContext.forward() not supported.

Comment: I found an example where context.forward() triggered from punctuator which was scheduled in Transformer: https://github.com/bbejeck/kafka-streams-in-action/blob/master/src/main/java/bbejeck/chapter_6/transformer/StockPerformanceTransformer.java. 
I see the difference that they schedule punctuator from init, and not from transform

Comment: Thanks @VasiliySarzhynskyi, I will try it but I need to reschedule on transform()... And the problem seems to be on the context instance, so I don't see how it could change from init() to transform(). Let see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, I found the answer in the javadoc about **ValueTransformerWithKey** interface:
https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/ValueTransformerWithKey.html

> Note, that using ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object) or ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object, To) is not allowed within transform and will result in an exception.

However, implementing the **Transformer** interface instead allows the usage of **context.forward()**. Thanks @Matthias J. Sax

https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html

> If more than one output record should be forwarded downstream ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object) and ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object, To) can be used. If record should not be forwarded downstream, transform can return null.

Comment: Yep, but it is not resolved, it does not answer the question. How can I forward an event ? Can I use the statestores to write something and then having a DSL logic defined somewhere ? It looks like I want the Punctuator to act like a source. Not sure how to plug that with the DSL.

Comment: You need to use `transform()` instead of `transformValues()` to be able to use `context.forward()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I looked at it in the other transformer interfaces with same note about not allowing forward usage, except Transformer interface itself which allows it. Thanks to point me on it again.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Using `transform()` instead of `transformValues()` calls trigger for a repartition. I don't change a key just a value, so I don't need downstream repartition. How can I do this with `transform()`? Seems I need a `transformValues()` behavior in this case, but I cannot use `context.forward()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot avoid the downstream repartition atm -- it's a gap the the API.