# Kafka Stream - How to send an alert if no event has been received for a given key during some amount of time

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I need to send an alert if no event has been received in a topic for a given key during some amount of time. What would be the best approach to solve this use case with KafkaStream ?

I tried:

1) a **windowedBy** together with a **suppress** operator:

```
    stream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
        .count()
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
        .filter((k, v) -> v == 0)
        .toStream()
        .map((windowId, count) -> KeyValue.pair(windowId.key(), AlarmEvent.builder().build()))
        .to(ALARMS, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), AlarmEvent.serde()));
```

But it seems that the window will not close until an event occurs after the expiration, thus no alarm can be send exactly after the defined timeout.

2) Using **processor** API with a **punctator**, it seems to work but I only tested with a **TopologyTestDriver** and **advanceWallClockTime()**. Not sure this advanceWallClockTime() relflects real time advance, or would only change upon event reception, thus falling back to the problem in 1).

3) If punctuator works, I would like to use it in a **ValueTranformer** to benefit from the DSL topology. However, I am encountering the problem described in [How to forward event downstream from a Punctuator instance in a ValueTransformer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357135/how-to-forward-event-downstream-from-a-punctuator-instance-in-a-valuetransformer). Cannot send event downstream from the punctuator instance.

4) Finally, I had the idea to inject some dummy events on a regular basis (eg. every second) for every partitions so as to artificially force the inner clock to advance. This would allows me to use the clean and simple DSL window and suppress operators.

Comment: Pretty interesting question, I guess ["Windowed aggregations over successively increasing timed windows"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Windowed+aggregations+over+successively+increasing+timed+windows) would be the useful starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> 2) Using processor API with a punctator, it seems to work but I only tested with a TopologyTestDriver and advanceWallClockTime(). Not sure this advanceWallClockTime() relflects real time advance, or would only change upon event reception, thus falling back to the problem in 1).

That is the right approach. As the name indicate, punctuations can be triggered based on wall-clock time (ie, system time). `TopologyTestDriver` mocks wall-clock time for testing purpose, but `KafkaStreams` will use system time.

> 3) If punctuator works, I would like to use it in a ValueTranformer to benefit from the DSL topology. However, I am encountering the problem described in How to forward event downstream from a Punctuator instance in a ValueTransformer?. Cannot send event downstream from the punctuator instance.

You need to use `transform()` instead. Emitting data via `forward()` is no allowed in punctuations of a `ValueTransformer` because you could emit any key, violating that contract of a non-modified key.

> 4) Finally, I had the idea to inject some dummy events on a regular basis (eg. every second) for every partitions so as to artificially force the inner clock to advance. This would allows me to use the clean and simple DSL window and suppress operators.

That should work, too.